# Yodlee "/authenticator/token" api not consistant

Tags: yodlee

Hi i am calling **"/authenticator/token"** Api to get authentication token for fastlink2.0 some time it works and some time it throw exception **"oauth_error_problem=invalid_url_access&oauth_error_code=418"** .I dont think its problem from in calling because when i call it again 2-4 times with same **Rsession** and **cobSessionToken** it will gives me token.

Can anyone help me what is the problem and,is fastlink 2.0 is stable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check followings-

- The URL you are using is correct.
- That you have not created any new userSession(RSession), as sometimes this ends up in mentioned error.

And yes, Fastlink 2 is very much stable and its working fine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer...But if URL is not correct then it should not work anytime but some time its working means URL is correct.second thing about Rsession so i am creating RSession once for user.

Comment: Can you please leave details about the environment you are using to Yodlee Chat present on developer.yodlee.com with your issue?